# In a multi-project setup, Gradle evaluates EVERY sub-project. Can I ignore some of the subprojects?

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-studio

I have the following multi-project setup in Gradle for building multiple Android apps which use a few libraries:

Let's say my root dir is `/workspace`

The directory structure is the following (it's incomplete):

```
/workspace/                         --> root dir for the gradle build
/workspace/settings.gradle
...             
/workspace/myapp1/Android/          --> contains the 1st app (has a build.gradle) 
/workspace/myapp2/Android/          --> contains the 2nd app (has a build.gradle) 
...
/market_licensing/library/          ---> contains a lib (has a build.gradle)
/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library/ ---> another lib (has a build.gradle)
```

`settings.gradle` in /workspace/ looks like this:

```
include ':market_licensing:library'
include ':play_apk_expansion:downloader_library'

include ':myapp1:Android'
include ':myapp2:Android'
```

When I run a gradle build in one of the app directories, it works:
For example, `/workspace/myapp1/Android>gradle clean` runs fine.

However, this will EVALUATE also the build.gradle project for `myapp2`.

This is expected according to the Gradle manual. In http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html, in part `56.3. Execution rules for multi-project builds` it says "Gradle always evaluates every project of the multi-project build and creates all existing task objects.".

My problem with this is that this slows down my builds unnecessarily. Unnecessarily because, when I'm building `myapp1`, I don't care about `myapp2`. I want the libraries to be in a good state, but I don't care about `myapp2`. This is not terrible for 2 apps, but imagine having 20 apps. I want to be able to build the app that I'm currently working on as fast as possible.

Is there a way to ignore other subprojects , even for the evaluation stage?
Or is there an alternative way to set up multiple projects that depend on the same libraries but don't depend on each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you pointed out the default behaviour in gradle is to evaluate all projects. There are plans (and also initial work started) to make this more fine grained in the future. For now you might checkout the incubating feature "configuration on demand". Maybe this helps you. have a look at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:cross_project_configuration for details

cheers,

René

Comment: Thanks! That works great from the command line. Follow up question: Do you happen to know how to make Android Studio do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android Studio, but there should be an option somewhere in the gradle configuration to add commandline options manually